# What is a way to pass data, not defined in forms, between steps in form wizard?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-formwizard

Currently, my form take in three variables:

Form for step 0:

```
class VerifyAccountsForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}), label="")
    Question1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}), label="")
    Question2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Verify password'}), label="")
```

Depending on the answer to Question 1 and 2: I will generate a variable 'data' in get_form() that will be used in step 1.

I am not sure how to pass 'data' to step 1.  Data seems to be erased when you use get_context_data() when moved to step 1. Because data is not a filed in forms, I don't think get_cleanted_data_for step() works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variable to the init of your form with the `get_form_kwargs` method:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self, step):
    if step == 'name-of-the-step-you-want-to-pass-data-to':
        prev_data = self.storage.get_step_data('name-of-previous-step')
        return {
            'something': prev_data.get('something'),
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify how would you implement this in init? like this?                              `def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.form_list = kwargs.pop('form_list')
        self.user_generated_data = kwargs.pop('user_generated_data')
        return super(VerifyUserAccounts, self).__init__(**kwargs)`

Comment: Okay I assume your form is VerifyUserAccounts then the init should be `def __init__ (self, data=None, something=None, *args, **kwargs): super(VerifyUserAccounts, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)` and then you anything you want with the something variable that you passed to the form. You dont return anything in the form init.

Comment: Thanks. because my data is not one of the fields in the form, how do I store the value?  storage.get_step_data seems only to grab value from the fields defined in the my forms, not data derived from my form.